# iPhone Facebook Friend Selector Pre Selected Friends

Tags: ios, facebook, multi-friend-selector

I am trying to decide if the built in Facebook Friend Selector is going to be the ideal way of going about what I want to achieve. I want to be able to select friends before the user sees the friend selector. Say I have a list of friends {Bill, Susy, Earl}, when the friend selector displays I want each of these names to be checked.

This seems to not be possible since the NSArray of selection is readOnly.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSArray *selection
Description The list of friends that are currently selected in the veiw. The items in the array are FBGraphUser objects.
```

Is there any way around this or should I just create my own friend selector?